# Flash drive is only recognized either/or by Chrome OS, Windows

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, windows-8.1, google-chrome-os

I have had problems recently after I formatted a USB flash drive on my Chromebook. When I plugged it in to my computer, it did not show a notification for the drive, or indicate that it recognized it in the "This PC (Computer)" menu.

To resolve this problem, I went to Computer Management > Disk Management > Right-clicked on the drive (it recognized it, but it just wasn't showing up) > New Simple Partition... > Followed the steps and formatted it to NTFS. I named it "Backups".

When I plugged it into my Chromebook, it recognized it, *but* it gave me a toast notification saying "Sorry, at least one partition on your device could not be mounted". When I opened it in the file manager, its name was "UNTITLED". When I put an empty folder on it, it did not show up in Windows.

I formatted the drive again in my Chromebook, and this time went to Windows and formatted it to a FAT32 filesystem, but I'm still having the same problems. The only help I found was [here](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1700055?hl=en&source=genius-rts), where I was told to reformat the drive on my Chromebook.

This was working before I formatted it on my Chromebook, what has happened?

Comment: You don't mention the size of the drive. One possible issue is that for smaller drives(e.g. 2 GB), plain FAT might be best, for very large, exFAT might be needed etc. Also, you might need to set the *allocation unit size*. See http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/format-16gb-usb-drive-ntfs-fat32/ for more on this.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The size of my drive is 29.8 GB, not that large compared to some other drives. I chose the allocation unit size that was pre-selected on Windows, 16 kilobytes.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik **Edit:** just tried exFAT, got the same error.

Comment: I'd suggest a *complete* reformat without partitioning, FAT32, default allocation unit size, performed on the Windows box, as that should restore it to original condition. If that was usable by Chrome before, it should still be.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I just finished formatting the drive after right-clicking > Format, setting everything to default and unchecking the "Quick Format" box. Still gives me the same error...

Comment: Though I've had an issue similar to yours and was eventually able to format the USB drive correctly by doing multiple full formats in FAT32 and exFAT, changing allocation unit size from default and  back, my repetitive attempts were somewhat random in nature. Though the drive *seems* to be working, I do not trust it fully. Perhaps you can dedicate it to one machine.

Comment: You could try formatting with https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/

Answer (score -1):

Disk formatted with chromeOS does not have any partitions. The disk itself is formatted.

Windows does require partitions, otherwise it cannot read the disk. You can format the disk in Windows but the data is than deleted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is nonsense.